# jQuery: how to read the name attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have little of an issue writing my script.

```
$(function(){
  $(".wolny").click(function() {
    var godzina = this.id;
    var minuta = this.name;
    alert(godzina + ":" + minuta);
  });
```

Alert should give me output looking like so hour:minute. Instead of that I am getting this: hour:undefined. I really dont know what to do :x

Here's HTML code (php generated)

```
<div class="col-sm-3 kafelek wolny" name="15" id="9"></div>
```

Thank's for any help.

Comment: Name isn't a property, but instead it's an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.attr()` function instead like so:

```
var minuta = $(this).attr('name');
```

This works because `name` in your case is a attribute and not a property. This will work with any random attribute like `foo` that you may add.

A better way is to add a data attribute like `data-name="something"` and read it with `$(this).data(name)`.

Working Example:

```js
$(function(){
   $(".wolny").click(function() {
      var godzina = this.id;
      var minuta = $(this).attr('name');
      alert(godzina + ":" + minuta);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 kafelek wolny" name="15" id="9"> Click me! </div>
```

Comment: it worked. Thank you very much ^^. I will mark your question as an answer as soon as I will be able to

Answer (score 2):

A `div` element doesn't technically *have* a `name` attribute.  If you want to store a piece of data, store it as a `data-*` attribute.  Something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 kafelek wolny" data-name="15" id="9"></div>
```

Then retrieve it as such:

```
var minuta = $(this).data('name');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".wolny").click(function() {
    var godzina = $(this).attr('id');
    var minuta = $(this).attr('name');
    alert(godzina + ":" + minuta);
  });
});
```

However, if possible, I would recommend using data attributes for your values. Here's an example:

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 kafelek wolny" data-hour="9" data-minute="15"></div>
```

Then, in the JavaScript, you use "data-hour" and "data-minute" for the attributes instead of "id" and "name" like it is now.